# Explain "SLIDER" drag and drop on protractor with a proper example

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(elem, target).perform();
```

I can clearly understand the above code but I cannot get how to specify this element and target.
Take this example

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(slider,{x:100, y:0}).perform();
```

In the website in which I'm working on, I cannot find any x, y or anything I can match with that and develop.

So it will be helpful if someone explains with some example for x and y so that I can relate to it and make I work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dragAndDrop()` has two ways to work.

One starts with the element to drag. Here `elem` works as normal `ElementFinder`, so something like `dragAndDrop(element(by.css('div.my-class')), target).perform();`.

Now the `target` works in two ways: Either as another `ElementFinder` like in `elem` or as coordinates to move, starting from the position of `elem`, moving x pixels horizontally and y pixels vertically (plus to the right or top, minus to the left or bottom). So `{x:100, y:0}` will move your slider 100 pixels to the right from the starting position.

`dragAndDrop(element(by.css('div.my-class')), {x:100, y:0}).perform();` will therefore move the `element(by.css('div.my-class'))` 100 pixels to the right.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Zwingli !!

Comment: it is showing this error > No element found using locator: By(css selector, div.classname)

Comment: Did you identify your slider-element correctly? Is it in a `<div>`-Tag, does it have a `class="classname"` and is it present and visible the moment you try to drag it?

Comment: Actually, it is not a div tag. It is a mdslider tag. I used mdslider instead of div tag.

Comment: So, you found the element now using `$('mdslider')`?
Evtl. check locators of the Protractor API and/or the list of CSS Selectors on w3schools